# search filtering columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

With Postgres, I need to filer a search on a table with 9 columns, I only need 4 of them, the first, the second, the sixth and the seventh.

What I need is a search result with this four columns only where 6th and 7th column are different keeping the sequence of 1st, 2nd, 6th and 7th on the result
Here is the example where 6th and 7th are children and bonus

I'm fairly new to this and i really appreciate if you can show me how to get this result.

```
psql=> select employee_id, registration, children, bonus from rewards_plan;
    employee_id   |  registration  | children | bonus  
--------------------+--------+----------+--------------
        65000 | 180047     |        1 |       1
        76000 | 154177     |        1 |       0
        97000 | 223181     |        2 |       1
        16000 | 195381     |        1 |       0
        25000 | 301554     |        1 |       1
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated, it worked just fine, awesome, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The WHERE clause is not restricted to the columns in the SELECT list.

You can use:

```
select employee_id, registration, children, bonus 
from rewards_plan
where sixth_column <> seventh_column;
```

If those two columns can contain NULL values you might want to use a "null-safe" comparison:

```
select employee_id, registration, children, bonus 
from rewards_plan
where sixth_column is distinct from seventh_column;
```